# How to present a recursive collection in JSP

Tags: jsp, user-interface, view, collections, jstl

I have a backend service which is returning me an `Info` object. This `Info` object has a list of `FolderGroup` objects which in turn has list of `FolderGroup` objects and so on.

Basically it is to represent folders and subfolders. But in my JSP page, I would not know till what depth it is present for me to iterate. How can this be handled with JSTL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a JSP tag file (`WEB-INF/tags/folderGroups.tag`) containing the following code:

```
<%@ attribute name="list" required="true" %>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myTags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:if test="${!empty list}">
    <ul>
    <c:forEach var="folderGroup" items="${list}">
        <li><c:out value="${folderGroup.name}"/></li>
        <myTags:folderGroups list="${folderGroup.subGroups}"/>
    </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</c:if>
```

The tag calls itself recursively to generate a folder tree.

And inside your JSP, do

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myTags" %>
...
<myTags:folderGroups list="${info.folderGroups}"/>
```

Comment: I had to add `type` to the attribute, otherwise I got it as a String.  
i.e  
    `<%@ attribute name="list" type="MyClass" required="true" %>`

Comment: I was using a set so i needed type="java.util.LinkedHashSet".