# Recursivity jsp

Tags: jsp, recursion

I'm having the same issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135376/how-to-present-a-recursive-collection-in-jsp):
A comment has a list of responses and each response has a list of responses and so on...

I would like to display the whole discussion thread:

in jsp, i have this:

```
<rec:write list="${comment.responses}" />
```

in the tag file:

```
<%@ attribute name="list" required="true" %>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="rec" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="logic" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic"%>



 <c:if test="${!empty list}">
        <ul>
        <c:forEach var="response" items="${list}">
            <li><c:out value="${response.content}"/></li>       
            <rec:write list="${response.responses}"/>   
        </c:forEach>

        </ul>
</c:if>
```

But i get this exception:

```
JspException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'content' not found on type java.lang.String
```

Comment: Have you tried iterating the variable `response` alone ?

Comment: It throws an StackOverFlow Exception!
But could u elaborate a little bit plz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so close, should have just added the list type:

```
<%@ attribute name="list" required="true" type="java.util.Set"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's not as simple as the fact you have mis-spelt response/responses in your jsp code (missing s)?

Rob.

Comment: No it's not a mis-spelling, that's how its written in French :)

Comment: Okay, fair point, let me re-phrase my question - I assume the jsp code object/field names match those of the underlying objects :) - I have just noticed that you have re-written your code. It looks like 'list' is actually a list of Strings, not whatever object type has the content and responses attributes.